# SFINAE technique for free function wrappers

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, sfinae, c++14

I would really like to be able to have a free function that adapts to whatever types its being given.

e.g.

```
template <typename T> bool ReadLine(T & reader, std::string & line) 
{
     return reader.ReadString(line); 
}
```

For some T, the correct function is reader.ReadString(buffer).  But for others, it should be reader.ReadLine(buffer).  And of course, there may be other patterns in the future.  The point being to adapt the free function ReadLine(from, into) to work with any reasonable set of from & into (I've forced the destination buffer to be a std::string to simplify things here).

Now, I can make a non-template version of ReadLine for any concrete type I want, but what I really need is the ability to partially specialize for classes of types, such that those which support the pattern reader.ReadString() all end up using that, and those which support reader.ReadLine() use that, and in the future I can add other patterns without disturbing anything that already works.

I'm aware that I can create a policy class, such as LineReaderPolicy, which knows for a given T which pattern to use (it would have to be partially specialized depending on T to map it to the correct pattern.

But is there a better, more C++14 way of solving this?

This is one of those "God it seems that templates are really, really close to being really, really useful... but for this constantly recurring problem..."

Compostability is better than ever with C++11/14, but it still seems that this fundamental problem is unsolved?  Or is it?!

How would you suggest I write a set of free functions that adapt to any reasonable T to read a line from it?  Whether T be a string stream, an output iterator, a file handle, a string, a string-view, etc., etc...

I just cannot think that C++ is really come of age until I can write a reasonable

```
template <typename T> size_t length(T t) { return t.size(); }
```

For which I can then extend that into any reasonable T, and stop having to write code that know so many details of T, but can inter-operate with tons of Ts via such flexible free function adapters...

Comment: Can you elaborate on why a policy class (to which the function could delegate) is not enough for your needs?

Comment: A policy class does work.  I just... wish it wasn't necessary.  I was hoping that there's a better way - something less full of syntactical mumbo-jumbo that more directly expresses the needed variations.

Comment: Also... how does a policy really solve the problem of "ideally, the compiler should choose what fits, nothing more, nothing less."  e.g. if I could just provide code-patterns, and the compiler tried each one and used whatever non-ambiguously worked, that would be far better than having to implement multiple policies for every possible T.  I don't even see how to make a policy class really do any better than fully specialized free functions + a default templated one...

Comment: _"t.ReadString(buffer). But for others, it should be s.ReadLine(buffer)"_ ... I assume you mean `reader.ReadString(line)`? I got quite confused reading the first paragraph wondering where all those new variables came from

Comment: Fixed that.  Sorry for the confusion :(

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you can ensure that at most one of `reader.ReadString` or `reader.ReadLine` is defined, use SFINAE to control overloading ([Live at Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/760cfb9c21d22482)):

```
template <typename T>
auto ReadLine(T& reader, std::string& line) -> decltype(reader.ReadString(line)) {
  return reader.ReadString(line); 
}

template <typename T>
auto ReadLine(T& reader, std::string& line) -> decltype(reader.ReadLine(line)) {
  return reader.ReadLine(line); 
}
```

The inapplicable implementation will trigger SFINAE and be removed from the overload set, leaving only the correct implementation.

<strike>In C++14 you'll be able to omit the trailing return type and simply use return type deduction.</strike>

In a future revision of C++, [Concepts Lite](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3701.pdf) will enable this to be done more cleanly. Given concepts that discriminate the two different kinds of readers - say `StringReader` and `LineReader`:

```
template <typename T>
concept bool StringReader() {
  return requires(T& reader, std::string& line) {
    {reader.ReadString(line)} -> bool;
  };
}

template <typename T>
concept bool LineReader() {
  return requires(T& reader, std::string& line) {
    {reader.ReadLine(line)} -> bool;
  };
}
```

you'll be able to directly constrain your implementations to the set of types that model those concepts:

```
bool ReadLine(StringReader& reader, std::string& line) {
  return reader.ReadString(line); 
}

bool ReadLine(LineReader& reader, std::string& line) {
  return reader.ReadLine(line); 
}
```

Hopefully you'll be able to reuse those concepts elsewhere to justify the "new-special-better" syntax being substantially longer than the old nasty syntax. Concepts Lite also will make it possible to handle types that model *both* concepts by explicit disambiguation:

```
template <typename T>
  requires StringReader<T>() && LineReader<T>()
bool ReadLine(T& reader, std::string& line) {
  // Call one, or the other, or do something completely different.
}
```

Comment: C++14 return type deduction does _not_ do SFINAE, by design, so if you want SFINAE you need to keep the trailing-return-type, or move the SFINAE to a default template argument: `template <typename T, typename Requires = decltype(std::declval<T&>().ReadString(std::declval<std::string&>()))> auto ReadLine(T& reader, std::string& line) { ... }`

Comment: @JonathanWakely Thank you for the correction. I had second thoughts about that assertion immediately upon posting the answer, and I've been scanning through N3936 trying to support it.

Comment: From the proposal [N3582 "Return type deduction for normal functions"](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3582.html): "SFINAE: Since the return type is deduced by instantiating the template, if the instantiation is ill-formed, this causes an error rather than a substitution failure. This allows an `auto` function to return a lambda, which is not possible using the `decltype(returned expression)` pattern."

Comment: Blast!  This appears to not be supported by MS VisualStudio 2013!!!
I get `error C2995: 'unknown-type Toolbox::GetName(T &)' : function template has already been defined` when I define more than one, varying on the interface that the given T provides.

Comment: @mordachai this failure of visual studio is called 'missing support for expression SFINAE'.

Comment: Oh, there are some extensions in vsvc that let you detect existence of methods.

Answer (score 3):

> I just cannot think that C++ is really come of age until I can write a reasonable
>
> ```
> template <typename T> size_t length(T t) { return t.size(); }
> ```
>
> For which I can then extend that into any reasonable T, and stop having to write code that know so many details of T, but can inter-operate with tons of Ts via such flexible free function adapters...

You want Concepts Lite, which I hope will arrive in C++17:

```
template<typename T>
  concept bool Has_size()
  {
    return requires(T t) {
      t.size() -> Integral;
    };
  }

template<typename T>
  concept bool Has_length()
  {
    return requires(T t) {
      t.length() -> Integral;
    };
  }

template <Has_size T> auto length(T t) { return t.size(); }
template <Has_length T> auto length(T t) { return t.length(); }
```

Until then you can use SFINAE to emulate it, which can be done in many ways, the tersest for your example is probably just a trailing-return-type as shown in Casey's answer.

```
template <typename T>
  auto length(T t) -> decltype(t.size()) { return t.size(); }
template <typename T>
  auto length(T t) -> decltype(t.length()) { return t.length(); }
```

Comment: This is cool - and the concepts lite is pretty cool - but I still think it's all overly restrictive and annoying.  What would be wrong with having the compiler look at every templated free function that is in scope, that fits the usage-pattern, and just use the one that doesn't fail to compile?  Yes, there are ambiguity issues possible, but that seems entirely manageable (or additional tools can be provided to deal with such ambiguities or undesirable pattern-matches), and just allow C++ to be a pattern engine - what templates were touted as being originally!

Comment: Compilation times would explode

Comment: That seems unlikely to me.  You'd have to have many overloads which were long and took the compiler real time to evaluate each possibility.  Bad designs could be created, of course, but they can now.

Comment: Instantiating templates is expensive, far more expensive than overload resolution, but you can believe what you want :)

Comment: The point is, you would have to process the entire body of a template, and potentially instantiate all the templates it uses and perform overload resolution for every function call in the body of the template, to find whether every function template can even be called, then _still_ have to do overload resolution with all other viable functions. With the current rules you just do one round of overload resolution.

Answer (score 1):

```
template<typename>struct type_sink{typedef void type;};
template<typename T>using TypeSink=typename type_sink<T>::type;
template<typename T,typename=void>
struct has_x:std::false_type{};
template<typename T>
struct has_x<T,TypeSink(decltype(std::declval<T>().x())>:std::true_type{};
```

is a pretty simple traits class for 'does a type have a `.x()` method, and can be generalized.

We can then use tag dispatching to direct our function to custom implementations.

```
template<typename T>
bool do_x_helper(T&t, std::true_type ){
  return t.x();
}
template<typename T>
bool do_x_helper(T7, std::false_type ){
  // alternative
}
template<typename T>
bool do_x(T& t){
  return do_x_helper( t, has_x<T>() );
}
```

This technique lets you have complex tests and method bodies.  You basically have to do overload resolution and dispatching manually, but it gives you full control.  It is similar to the techniques that `std` algorithms use to dispatch iterator types: in that case more than just `true_type` and `false_type` is dispatched on.

Comment: This seems like way to low-level syntax-heavy semantic-lite way to solve the issue.  I grant you this works, gives tons of control, and can be extended.  But man!  Seriously?  What a lot of gobbledeegook to say "if it support ReadLine, use that, if it supports ReadString, use that!"  (and of course allow for some future ReadAString, ReadOneLine, etc.,)